# Get querystring array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, parameters, query-string

I have a form that uses the get method and contains an array:

`http://www.example.com?name[]=hello&name[]=world`

I'm trying to retrieve array values 'hello' and 'world' using JavaScript or jQuery.

I've had a look at similar solutions on Stack Overflow (e.g. [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)) but they seem to only deal with parameters rather than arrays.

Is it possible to get array values?

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/295783 in the link you posted will work in your case too, unless the parms repeat as suggested by you mentioning array and the use of []

Comment: Just to be clear: The URL does not have the concepts of *arrays*. All you have are multiple parameters with the same name. The `[]` are typically used for PHP servers, which will then created arrays out of these parameters. Other languages (e.g. Python) can handle multiple parameters with the same name (and without `[]`) just fine.

Comment: From the question you linked to, you might find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9362596/218196.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. Apologies I thought it was an array. 'name' is a checkbox form so multiple values are sent with the same name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mm6Bt/1/

```
function getURLParam(key,target){
    var values = [];
    if (!target) target = location.href;

    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");

    var pattern = key + '=([^&#]+)';
    var o_reg = new RegExp(pattern,'ig');
    while (true){
        var matches = o_reg.exec(target);
        if (matches && matches[1]){
            values.push(matches[1]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!values.length){
        return null;   
    } else {
        return values.length == 1 ? values[0] : values;
    }
}

var str = 'http://www.example.com?name[]=hello&name[]=world&var1=stam';

console.log(getURLParam('name[]',str));
console.log(getURLParam('var1',str));
```

Comment: After a lot of struggling, I figured out that we need to append [] to name if it is an array! looks obvious now, but somehow I wasted an hour to notice it.

Comment: Also, I replaced 4th line with: "target = decodeURIComponent(location.search);" to get this function to work.

Comment: is there a way to return whole query string as object instead of passing params?

Comment: I also need this to match empty string, can anyone update it please?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: this doesnt work if you have arrays like this: ?name[first]=John&name[last]=doe