# JS: Check Query String for GET variables that are not in an array?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an address of:

`www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3`

I want to enter that into an input field like this (value would obviously initially be blank):

`<input id="my-input-field" value="www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3">`

Then I want JS to parse everything after the `?`, take all of the queries ("a", "b", "c") and see if they exist in an `array()`.

Then I want to display a message stating that some of the items in the given URL were missing - but that's the easy part.

The part that I'm having trouble figuring out is: **how to break down the URL and only find the first part of each query?**

---

I understand how to strip everything before the question mark (including the question mark):

```
var str = "www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("?") + 1);
alert(str);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xx3fwhvv/

This returns: `a=1&b=2&c=3`

---

The next step could be to split the string up per each `&`?

```
var str = "a=1&b=2&c=3";
str = str.split("&");
alert(str);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lo24byo/

This returns: `a=1,b=2,c=3`

---

We can then remove everything after the `=`'s sign like this:

```
var str = 'a=1';
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('='));
alert(str);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfzvu5mh/

This results in: `a`

The thing now is how do I loop through the array and do this for each item? That would be the step I need to take.

---

Then I need to have an array like:

```
var myArray = array('a','c','d');
```

In the above array, cross checking the array that we created above to see if any of the values match up should return `b` as not matching up, as it's not in `myArray`.

This is where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated. I'm not very good with JS but I've been working at this trying to figure it out.

---

All together so far, the code would look something like this:

```
var str = "www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3";
newStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("?") + 1);
strArray = newStr.split("&");

i = 1;
for {
  newStrArray = strArray[i].substring(0, strArray[i].indexOf('='));
  i++;
}
```

The above doesn't work for me, but something like that any way.

---

EDIT (I'll be actively editing this part until the question is answered):

```
var str = "www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3";
var newStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("?") + 1);
var myStringArray = newStr.split("&");

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  myStringArray = myStringArray[i].substring(0, myStringArray[i].indexOf('='));
  alert(myStringArray[i]);
}
```

Current Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03ho0nbz/

Comment: Try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15866004/456135)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get querystring array values in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865747/get-querystring-array-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @anu thanks for your comment! I've searched around, my issue isn't how to get the query strings from the URL though, just need to break them up and compare them.

Comment: @anu in your second link, I also don't need to get the values for specific query get values, which is what every question on SO seems to be getting at.

Comment: Using the function given in my previous comment you can get an array of query params. Use that array to compare

Comment: @anu, again, thanks for the comment, I'm interested in all the input there is. I'm actually able to get the array, that's not the problem, it's the comparing part. I don't see anything in the code in those answers that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're overwriting your array with the result of a substring:

> myStringArray = myStringArray[i].substring(0, myStringArray[i].indexOf('='));

myStringArray receives the results of the substring, turning it into a string.

To compare *myArray* with *otherArray* and see if an element not exists in *myArray* you can use the indexOf() function:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'c', 'd'];
var otherArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i=0;i<otherArray.length;i++) { 
    if(myArray.indexOf(otherArray[i]) === -1) {
        console.log('myArray does not have', otherArray[i]); // myArray does not have b
    }
}
```

Going by your example this would create a loop looking something like:

```
var str = "www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3";
var newStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("?") + 1);
var myStringArray = newStr.split("&");
var myArray = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
  var eqIndex = myStringArray[i].indexOf('=');
  if(eqIndex !== -1) {
      var key = myStringArray[i].substring(0, eqIndex);
      if(myArray.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          alert(key, "not in myArray!");
      }
  }
}
```

Note that this way of writing JS is fine for learning practices, but if you intend to use JS in a professional setting, please read up on some JS good practices.

What i would do is to fiddle around with JS like you're doing, try and see if you can buy some JS good practices books and also look at how popular frameworks solve things. For professional purpose it's almost always a good idea to use a framework that's well maintained and supported. For example if you would use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) in this case you could do something like:

```
var paramKeys = _.chain("a=1&b=2&c=3".split('&')).map(function(params) {
    var p = params.split('=');
    return p[0];
}).value();
_.difference(paramKeys, ['a', 'c', 'd']) // "b"
```

Comment: Hi, Elwin! I'm just working this out still with what you've been providing. I'm still stuck on the first part, I just updated it a little more at the bottom.

Comment: Is the double loop what is bad practice?

Comment: I've added a working example in the second code block

Comment: Yeah, that is amazing. Thank you very much! Could you possibly provide some insight as to what about this is not good practice though? I really appreciate your time.

Comment: What i would do is to fiddle around with JS like you're doing, try and see if you can buy some JS good practices books and also look at how popular frameworks solve things. For professional purpose it's almost always a good idea to use a framework that's well maintained and supported. For example if you'de use underscore in this case you could do:
`_.difference(['a','b','c'], ['a', 'c', 'd']) // "b"`

Answer (score 1):

@mattroberts33 I am unable to understand why you are checking first parameter in the url, is there anything deference from www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3 to www.example.com/index.php?b=2&a=1&c=3. I would encourage read parameters based on the keys instead of index. In any url query parameters might jumbled.

Below method will return parameter by passing key and url to the method:

```
var getParameterByName = function (name, url) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
if (url) {
  var results = regex.exec(url);
} else {
  var results = regex.exec(location.search);
}
return results == null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));};
```

If you still wants to get based on index we can modify above method, But that is not encouraging.

Comment: I don't think it matters to be in any particular order. I'm comparing the query variables provided in the url to those available in a predetermined array, then telling the user which query variables are not available.